# перезапись свойст объекта JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
//соханим начальные настройки
var def = Object.assign({}, this.curSet);
// выберем все брейкпоинты из настроек
var query = [];
for (var key in def.media) {
  query.push(def.media[key].point);
}
// фукция устанавливает настройки для запуска
function setNewSettigs(mql) {
  var newSet = Object.assign({}, def);
  for (var key in newSet.media) {
    for (var prop in newSet.media[key]) {
      if (newSet.media[key][prop] == mql.media) { // вот здесь в IE10+ всегда false
        for (var set in newSet.media[key].settings) {
          if (set in newSet) {
            newSet[set] = newSet.media[key].settings[set];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return newSet;
}
// функция производит действия при совпадении медиа выражения
function run(mql) {
  if (mql.matches) {
    this.curSet = Object.assign({}, setNewSettigs(mql));
    console.log(this.curSet)
    this.start();
    console.log(mql.media)
  } else {
    this.curSet = Object.assign({}, def);
    this.start();
  }
}
// создадим медиа запросы и повесим обработчики на них
query.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
  var mql = window.matchMedia(arr[i]);
  mql.addListener(run.bind(this));
  run.call(this, mql);
}, this);
```

Добрый день, под спойлером код, с помощью которого я хочу перезапускать инициализацию объекта с новыми параметрами ориентируясь на медиа запросы, используя machmedia.
Выглядит создание объекта следующим образом:

```
var obj = new Obj({
        elem: document.querySelector('.CSSClass'),
        count: 4,
        // это объект с контрольными точками и свойствами которые нужно перезаписать
        media: {
            point1: {
                // контрольная точка
                point: 'only screen and (max-width: 768px)',
                // перезаписываемые свойства
                settings: {
                    count: 3,
                }
            },
            point2: {
                point: 'only screen and (max-width: 480px)',
                settings: {
                    count: 1,
                }
            },
        }
    });
```

И казалось бы все прекрасно работает(за исключением одного нюанса, о нем ниже), но стоило открыть мне IE и увы.... Функция `setNewSettigs` из кода под спойлером не перезаписывает параметры настроечного объекта на значения из `settigs` кода выше, причем 9-ка отрабатывает нормально, а вот уже начиная с 10-ки такой казус. Вопрос: Почему так происходит. Кто поможет разобраться?

P.s. А теперь про нюанс о котором выше.
в настройках 2 контрольные токи, на 768рх и 480рх. Параметр `count` - отвечает за количество отображаемых блоков в текущем экране.
Так вот, когда идет уменьшение экрана все хорошо на 768 отображается 3 блока, на 480 1, но вот когда начинаешь увеличивать окно снова после 480, казалось бы нужно после прохождения порога в 481 отображать 3 блока, так это вписывается в диапазон 768. Но в скрипте стоит запуск с исходными настройками если нет совпадений медиазапросе, как можно сделать так, что бы скрипт запоминал что между выставленными контрольными точками должны применяться настройки большего экрана?

**Обновление вопроса.**

Потестив код, выяснилось, что не срабатывает условие `newSet.media[key][prop] === mql.media` и  при переборе свойств выражение всегда возвращает `false`, в следствии чего и не перезаписываются свойства.... Почему себя так ведут иешки 10+ ? Баг или как же правильно сделать?
Для чего нужно это сравнение - когда идет обход объектов внутри параметра `media` в настройках, сраниваются значение его свойств со значением mql.media который пришел в функцию и если есть совпадение идет перезаписывание свойств из settings, того объекта в котором было совпадение.
 `mql` -  это экземпляр `window.matchmedia`, он создается в цикле по `query` (последний цикл в коде под спойлером). У него есть свойство `media`, в котором храниться строка медиа запроса.
`newSet.media[key][prop]` - здесь проход по свойствам объекта `media`, которые в свою очередь так же объекты в которых есть свойство point - так же строка для медиа запроса. Так вот как раз и проверяется на совпадение строки из mql.media со строкой из newSet.media[key].point

Comment: прям целый роман, есть краткая версия?

Comment: @Hipster а нужна?

Comment: что хранится в `newSet.media[key][prop]` и что в `mql.media`? Сделай [mcve]

Comment: @Grundy обновил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось при задании настроек я писал:

```
media: {
            point1: {
                point: 'only screen and (max-width: 768px)',
                settings: {
                    count: 3,
                }
            },
            point2: {
                point: 'only screen and (max-width: 480px)',
                settings: {
                    count: 1,
                }
            },
        }
```

При создании экземпляра window.matchmedia в его свойство media попадало: 'only screen and (max-width:480px)'. Т.е. между двоеточием и значением нету пробела. Поэтому - то иешки и говорили что они не равны.....
Причем этот пробел убирают только иешки 10+

```
'only screen and (max-width: 768px)' == 'only screen and (max-width:768px)' // false
```